# StAXON - Force specific value to be String when autoPrimitive is true

Tags: java, json, xml, wso2, stax

When using StAXON to convert an XML payload into JSON, is it possible to flag specific nodes so that when converting, they do not adhere to the `autoPrimitive(true)` property?

I have some XML:

```
<root>
    <foo>1234</foo> <!-- foo should always be String -->
    <bar>5678</bar> <!-- bar should always be Integer -->
</root>
```

And I want it to be converted into the following JSON:

```
{
    "foo": "1234", // Note: this value is a String
    "bar": 5678 // autoPrimitive setting has caused a type conversion
}
```

I'm aware that I can use the XML processing instruction `<? xml-multiple myNode ?>` when dealing with arrays, so is there something similar I can use to ensure certain nodes in XML are not automatically converted to their respective primitive types? The problem I am having is that both `foo` and `bar` are converted to numbers due to their values.

For reference, I am trying to make use of WSO2's ESB 4.9.0, which uses the StAXON library when dealing with XML -> JSON, and JSON -> XML conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to flag each node if it should be converted this manner. You can disable autoPrimitives globally by setting following,

Open ESB_HOME/repository/conf/synapse.properties, and set

```
synapse.commons.json.json.output.autoPrimitive=false
```

Comment: OK, thanks. If I change this setting, what happens when I have a value that I want to always be numeric in JSON? For example I have fields that are IDs, so must always be represented as numerical.

Comment: That is not possible AFAIK. If you set this, numbers will always be converted as Strings.